# Can an auto policy cover their insured when they intentionally ram someone else’s vehicle?

Tags: united-states, california, vandalism, car-insurance

**Problem:**

Alice is a policy holder for uninsured/under-insured motorist losses with insurer A; Bob has *most likely* no insurance coverage for intentional losses he caused at least not to property damages with insurer B.

Bob intentionally rams Alice’s vehicle on a public road; insurer B denies intentionality on behalf of Bob, and declines liability; however, not on the grounds that Bob is not covered for intentional losses.

Alice reports the matter to her insurer, and they assume liability, but once they receive the denial not based on lack of coverage, insurer A denies liability. Now the onus is on Alice to prove that Bob did not, in fact, not have coverage, and was “uninsured” by a reasonably clear standard.

This could be met by a showing that it would be illegal for insurer B to insure Bob since neither insurer A or Bob owes a duty to Alice to reveal their contract.

In fact, all laws in effect at the time of entering into the contract is, as if by reference, cited in the contract itself therefore, the public policy would, by the operation of law, void a provision that would allow such a coverage.

**ADDITIONAL FACTS**: Bob is bankrupt, and insurer B denies liability on alleged facts based on evidence it will not share absent a court order that which it interprets so as to conclude Alice is at fault instead of admitting on Bob's behalf a finding of intentional wrongdoing, and deny liability on the basis of lack of coverage.

**Questions:**

Is it against public policy to insure a motorist for intentional property damage caused by the insured with their vehicle to another’s property excluding covering any damage to the property of the insured?

Is it, in the State of California or is it prohibited by federal law? And if so, what laws or precedent prohibits it?

Primarily interested in the above jurisdictions, but any other would be interesting for comparison!

Comment: You probably can't insure against willful acts as such.  You might be able to insure against unforeseen consequences of willful acts though.

Comment: That is basically what’s spelled out in case law in California — see my answer.

Comment: I mean it's not an insurance contract at that point.  It's an option contract.  You would be buying a right to be paid for committing an act.  It wouldn't matter that it would be someone else getting paid because they would be paid to satisfy your liability to them.

Comment: I looked at my own Colorado uninsured motorist policy, and it explicitly says that it covers the case when the other driver had insurance but their insurer denies coverage.  There's no limitation based on the reason for such denial.  So if Alice's policy is similar (not sure what California requires), then it seems that the question is moot and Insurer A simply has to pay up.

Comment: Yes, insurer B denying coverage would make the matter much more straight forward, but insurer B does not deny coverage because the only way for it to do that would be to assert that Bob wrongfully and intentionally caused loss to Alice (since Bob _does_ have coverage for non-intentional losses he causes). Instead insurer B asserts that Alice is at fault, and acknowledges coverage based on its alleged facts where Bob not only is not liable, but in fact, Alice is at fault.

Comment: This is why Alice now has to prove it by a "reasonably clear" standard (Ins. Code § 790(h)(5))  to insurer A, that insurer B could not have had coverage as Alice and insurer A both had agreed that Bob acted intentional.

Comment: Insurer B may not "[k]nowingly [... m]isrepresent[] to claimants pertinent facts or insurance policy provisions relating to any coverages at issue" (Ins. Code § 790(h)(1)), but it does not have a disclosure duty to Alice, and is not prohibited to conceal the same from her. So, that is why it is important for Alice to prove that Bob was, by the operation of law, not covered.

Comment: Bob's liability policy exists, and Insurer B refuses to pay Alice's claim.  In what sense is that not "denying coverage"?

Comment: Do you mean 790.03(h)(5)?  That deals with unfair business practices.  So your question isn't about who is actually liable for the crash, but is about whether B is likely to get in trouble with the Insurance Commissioner over their conduct here?

Comment: Bob's liability policy does not exist for the purposes of intentional acts; it does for accidents, not for him to ram other cars and not have to suffer the liability. But insurer B denies intentionality, in fact, states Alice is at fault, under this theory, Bob would is not an uninsured motorist for insurer A's purposes, but simply one not deemed at fault by insurer B. So everyone happy, because both insurer A and B got their money at the beginning of the month, and neither had to pay a penny to either party. Alice's only recourse is going from the angle insurer A admitted: Bob was willful.

Comment: Now, she has to prove Bob was, in fact, uninsured or underinsured since the other fact is undisputed and agreed to by insurer A. Based on the cites in my answer: A policy would be unlawful and void since clearly in violation of public policy, and that means insurer A has come to reason and, as you said, has to pay up. (Yes, 790.03, sorry!)

Comment: "This could be met by a showing that it would be illegal for insurer B to insure Bob since neither insurer A or Bob owes a duty to Alice to reveal their contract." Why would you think this is true. At least in litigation, insurance coverage must be disclosed.

Comment: "Bob is bankrupt, and insurer B denies liability on alleged facts based on evidence it will not share absent a court order that which it interprets so as to conclude Alice is at fault instead of admitting on Bob's behalf a finding of intentional wrongdoing, and deny liability on the basis of lack of coverage." This is subject to compulsory discovery in litigation. There is no insurer-insured privilege.

Comment: @ohwilleke actually, you are right! Misrepresentation generally includes concealment, too, and I don't see a reason as to why that would not apply here! Insurer B would generally have a duty to disclose pertinent policy related facts and provisions per § 790.03(h)(1) — that may mean that certain clauses may be kept confidential absent a subpoena. "This is subject to compulsory discovery in litigation." For sure.

Comment: Alice probably has a duty to sue Bob at the insurance company's request (or it could sue Bob directly) for subrogation.

Comment: I would agree with the latter.

Answer (score 4):

My findings so far are:

It does appear to be against public policy at least in California and Oregon.

**In California outlawed statutorily — [Ins. Code § 533](https://casetext.com/statute/california-codes/california-insurance-code/division-1-general-rules-governing-insurance/part-1-the-contract/chapter-6-loss/article-2-causes-of-loss/section-533-willful-act-of-insured-negligence-of-insured) provides:**

> “An insurer is not liable for a loss caused by the wilful act of the insured; but he is not exonerated by the negligence of the insured, or of the insured’s agents or others.”

Also on point is [Civ. Code, § 1668](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?sectionNum=1668.&lawCode=CIV):

> “All contracts which have for their object, directly or indirectly, to exempt anyone from responsibility for his own fraud, or willful injury to the person or property of another, or violation of law, whether willful or negligent, are against the policy of the law."

Affirmed, for e.g., in *Tomerlin v. Canadian Indem. Co.*, [61 Cal.2d 638, 39 Cal. Rptr. 731, 394 P.2d 571](https://casetext.com/case/tomerlin-v-canadian-indemnity-co?q=Ins.%20Code%20%C2%A7%20533&PHONE_NUMBER_GROUP=P&sort=relevance&p=1&type=case&jxs=casct&tab=keyword) (Cal. 1964)

> “[A]n insurer may not indemnify against liability caused by the insured's wilful wrong (Civ. Code, § 1668; Ins. Code, § 533; see, e.g., *Abbott v. Western Nat. Indem. Co.* (1958) 165 Cal.App.2d 302, 305 [ 331 P.2d 997])”

**In Oregon, Outlawed by case law:**

> “Despite variations in the language of the policies, this court has interpreted various policy provisions excluding insurance coverage for intentionally-caused injuries similarly. [...] For an exclusion from insurance coverage for intentional conduct to apply, "[i]t is not sufficient that the insured's  intentional, albeit unlawful, acts have resulted in unintended harm; the acts must have been committed for the purpose of inflicting the injury and harm before either a policy provision excluding intentional harm applies or the public policy against insurability attaches." [Citation.]” *Ledford v. Gutoski*, [319 Or. 397, 877 P.2d 80](https://casetext.com/case/ledford-v-gutoski-1) (Or. 1994)

Comment: The language in Pennsylvania precedent sounds like it says that you don't lose coverage just because you are driving a getaway car in a bank robbery.  It doesn't mean that you won't lose coverage if you hit someone willfully, only that you won't lose coverage if you hit someone accidentally during a crime.  This is unlike California'a 1668 (which you cited), which says "willful or negligent."

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, I'll edit! "Negligent" seems to describe "violation of law", and not "willful injury to the person or property of another".

Comment: If the purpose of mandatory liability insurance is to ensure that people who are injured get paid even if the people causing the injury are judgment-proof, saying that an insurance company doesn't have to pay an injured person for deliberate actions would undermine that objective.  Note that a liability company should not indemnify someone who causes deliberate damage, but should instead pursue recovery against them at least as aggressively as the injured party would in the absence of insurance, but I don't see what's wrong with ensuring that innocent injured parties get paid.

Comment: @supercat I think you're missing the point: Those insured and injured will get paid this way; this is how they can get paid even if the other party acted willfully. The second point: Yes, and no. They don't "indemnify" the deliberate actor, they merely reimburse their own insured, and then they have the opportunity to sue.

Comment: @kisspuska: If Bob deliberately injures Alice, would Alice be regarded as "the insured" by Bob's liability insurance company?

Comment: @supercar No, she is simply the insured of her own insurer. Bob's insurer has zero liability. Alice's insurer may sue Bob in his private capacity or, if prosecuted on behalf of the People, statutory restitution will be ordered payable towards the insurer in the criminal proceedings.

Comment: @kisspuska: What if the injured party has no insurance (e.g. the injured party is a pedestrian)?

Comment: Indemnification of a party for their own intentional tortious conduct is prohibited in every jurisdiction. It is conceivable that there could still be insurance coverage if it was a company car that the employee just used, or to the extent of the third-party car lender's loss, so long as the driver was not indemnified.

Answer (score 1):

### Probably, but the issue doesn't arise

No legitimate insurance company would offer such a policy because it exposes them to an almost certain loss: the only person who would want such a policy is a person who was planning to cause damage.

And since insurance is highly [regulated](http://www.insurance.ca.gov/01-consumers/130-laws-regs-hearings/) in California, and everywhere else, legitimate insurers are all you get.

### However, that just begs the question ...

For the scenario you present, Alice is not interested in Bob's arrangement with his insurer. Bob caused the damage to Alice's property (willfully or negligently), therefore, Bob has a liability to Alice. Whether Bob's insurer will indemnify Bob is a matter of complete indifference to her (as a matter of law - if the insurer accepts liability, things will be easier but the legal issues don't change).

Similarly, the refusal of Bob's insurer to assume liability does not affect whether Alice can claim on her insurance. Alice's insurer should cover her and seek recompense from Bob.

### However, that just begs the other question ...

> Is it against public policy to insure a motorist for intentional property damage caused by the insured with their vehicle to another’s property excluding covering any damage to the property of the insured?

Intentional damage to property can be a perfectly normal and legal thing to do. For example, builders intentionally damage buildings, utility companies intentionally damage roads and footpaths, rescue services intentionally damage property by cutting people out of cars. All of these people carry insurance that will respond if they are negligent and cause *other* damage but who pays for the damage otherwise is usually a matter of contract or statutory law.

However, I think you mean not just intentional but *unlawful*. If so, it's complicated.

Common law "public policy" and even statutory prohibitions like the one you quote in your answer from Claifornia are not clear-cut and depend on circumstances.

For example, imagine your car has stalled on a railway level crossing and the lights start to flash. I intentionally ram your car with mine pushing us both through the level crossing to safety. There is no doubt that I willfully caused damage to your property but I did not act unlawfully because I have the defence of necessity - plus, I'm a hero. Depending on the exact wording of the policy, I may or may not be covered by my insurance but if I were, an argument by the insurer that they were statutorily barred from paying is likely to fail.

Different jurisdictions fall on different sides of the "public interest" argument with some prohibiting such contracts, others allowing them and, others allowing indemnity for legal defences and damages but not state levied fines (e.g. in the case of directors and officers liability cover).

Comment: It’s not as regulated as it may seem, I can assure you. But, yes, it would be nuts for them to do so, but what I’m hoping to know is whether I’m there is case law on this. I could look up and past precedent prohibiting liability insurance against punitive damage awards which resonates with the question, but it is not as broad as an affirmative answer to this would need to be.

Comment: Insurance companies are required to have an evidentiary threshold no higher than set by a “reasonably clear” standard yet they will be _literally_ happy to dispute what they see with their own eyes.

Comment: Added a hypo for the issue!

Comment: (+1 because the answer looked a lot less correct after the changes I made after the question was submitted,)

Comment: Agreed, based on my research, self-defense is an exception to the exclusionary clause, and I am sure that necessity would be treated similarly. The problem with the scenario outlined in the question is insurer A once having received the denial on the grounds asserted by insurer B makes it plausible for ins. A to assert insurer B admits coverage, and by that, it excludes Alice's coverage under her policy against un- and underinsured motorists. The objective is for Alice to exercise her right under Ins. Code §§ 790-790.15 in that insurer A promptly, fairly & equitably pay under her policy.

Comment: You are getting into details of how the insurance industry works which is often not directly related to the legal rights and responsibilities. Insurers make commercial decisions - sometimes to pay when they don't think they have liability, sometimes to deny when they think they do. This doesn't change the legal liability between Bob & Alice.

Comment: Insurers also have a legal, statutory duty because of, for e.g., Insurance Code being read into all the insurance contracts: Insurer A, and insurer B may each have a legal duty, and that is at the heart of this question not necessarily whether Alice could obtain remedial judgment on a court. This is about whether one has a statutory right, read into these contracts, to certain remedies I the above fact pattern from their insurer. Added more facts to make it nice and round.

Comment: Also, one of the cases cited specifically name "willful wrong":

“[A]n insurer may not indemnify against liability caused by the insured's wilful wrong (Civ. Code, § 1668; Ins. Code, § 533; see, e.g., Abbott v. Western Nat. Indem. Co. (1958) 165 Cal.App.2d 302, 305 [ 331 P.2d 997])”

Unlawful would be more restrictive as the law appears to stand which include potentially not unlawful, but otherwise blameworthy conduct.

Comment: "the refusal of Bob's insurer to assume liability does not affect whether Alice can claim on her insurance." Not true for UIM coverage.

Comment: It is by the operation of law if insurer A takes notice of malice in Bob’s injuring of Alice’s vehicle.

Comment: In this particular case the analysis is kind of right. Either no insurance covers it, or every insurance covers it because the state insurance law requires everybody to have it. So it boils down to what coverage the state financial liability law requires to exist.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it against public policy to insure a motorist for intentional
> property damage caused by the insured with their vehicle to another’s
> property excluding covering any damage to the property of the insured?

Insurance companies are not permitted to indemnify their insured for their insured's intentional tortious acts.

But, if the loss is otherwise covered by the insurance policy of someone other than the person who committed the intentional act (e.g. an employer of Bob with its own insurance) and the person whose insurance policy covers the loss has an insurable interest (e.g. because they have potential liability as an employer for Bob's on the job acts), that wouldn't usually be barred by law or public policy (unless the employer directed Bob to take the intentional act).

> Is it, in the State of California or is it prohibited by federal law?
> And if so, what laws or precedent prohibits it?

California law, although every U.S. jurisdiction has this rule rooted in English common law as other answers show.

**Other**

UIM insurance should cover Alice if Bob's insurer doesn't provide coverage due to an exclusion for intentional acts. But, UIM insurance only has a duty to pay if Bob lacks insurance, so his insurer's coverage decision is material to Alice's claim against her own insurer.

The insurance policies of both sides and the basis for Bob's insurer's denial of coverage should be disclosed in Alice's litigation with Bob suing for money damages.

Typically, Alice would file a declaratory judgment action against her own insurer, either separately or as a co-defendant in the action against Bob, to assure her that either Bob's insurance or her own, will cover the risk in a consistent manner. Often, the declaratory judgment action would be resolved by a stipulation based upon a special verdict in the suit against Bob determining if it is liable for battery or for mere negligence.

Typically, Bob's insurer would provide a defense to him subject to a reservation of rights (determined in a separate declaratory judgment action between Bob and his insurance company), notwithstanding its provisional denial of coverage, unless the evidence of his intent was unequivocally clear (e.g. a statement he made to his insurance company that his acts were intentional). The evidence provided to his insurance company that it used to deny his claim would be obtainable by discovery and admissible in Alice's lawsuit against Bob.

Also, even if Alice's UIM insurer did pay her right away, Alice would probably have to either sue Bob (subject to an insurance company lien at the insurance company's expense) or the insurance company would sue Bob for enforcement of its subrogation claim against Bob standing in Alice's shoes with cooperation from Alice that she would be contractually obligated to provide to her insurance company in that lawsuit (assuming in either case that Bob has some assets other than the insurance policy to pursue).

Comment: "But, UIM insurance only has a duty to pay if Bob lacks insurance, so his insurer's coverage decision is material to Alice's claim against her own insurer." I disagree in the instant fact pattern. It is immaterial so long as insurer A does not dispute and/or comes to a conclusion that the act was intentional. Once "[that fact has] become reasonably" (Ins. Code § 790.03(h)(5), by the operation of law, insurer A may not deem insurer B to have had coverage regardless of what Bob or insurer B contends. It was an import fact here that insurer A agreed on Bob's intentionality.

Comment: If the UIM admits intentional act and by virtue of that, non-coverage, and is denying coverage, then Alice's insurer loses the dec action brought by Alice on summary judgment. Also, while Bob's insurer can't pay Bob, suppose Bob is on the job and covered by Bob's employer's insurance. Bob's employer isn't necessarily barred from coverage by Bob's intentional acts for coverage of its own respondiat superior liability. I think a court would be hesitant to speculate on "reasonable clear" when this information would be disclosed at the outset in a lawsuit against Bob.

Comment: @kisspuska In particularly, the UIM insurer would want confirmation that Bob's policy isn't covering because sometimes Bob's insurer might cover the loss not withstanding the fact that a third-party thinks that it doesn't have to and is barred by public policy from doing so (e.g. due to fact it knows that Alice and her insurer do not know).

Comment: "[T]hen Alice's insurer loses [...]" Agreed. But Bob's employer would be barred from effectively providing coverage for its own agent under Civ. Code § 1668 or under "[§] 1608 provid[ing] that "[i]f any part of a single consideration for one or more objects, or of several considerations for a single object, is unlawful, the entire contract is void[" as §] 1667 broadly defines "unlawful" to include terms "[... c]ontrary to the policy of express law, though not expressly prohibited; or, [o]therwise contrary to good morals." (_Ambroselli v. Anapolsky_ (Sep. 26, 2017, C080751) Cal.App.3d [pp. 8])

Comment: @kisspuska This isn't how the public policy against insuring intentional acts works. The employer is protecting itself against its employee's unauthorized bad acts for which it has legal responsibility. The employer's liability isn't for intentional acts (except in the rare case where Bob is acting at his employer's instruction). The employer has vicarious strict liability for Bob and that liability is insurable.

Comment: @kisspuska Suppose Bob's employer's insurer pays Alice's judgment against Bob's employer. Then the Bob's employer's insurance company has a subrogation action against Bob for everything it had to pay to Alice as a result of his actions.

Comment: I think I'm getting to see your point!

Comment: Note that CA Ins. Code § 533 clearly distinguishes between the insured and the agents of the insured.

Comment: Although the fact pattern does not consider Bob to be in employ of anyone who could be deemed to have vicarious liability for Bob’s actions (including intentional ones), but even in that case: Alice only needs to prove that Bob’s vehicle was an “uninsured motor vehicle” (Ins. Code § 11580.2) for the purposes of Ins. Code read into her policy to apply and render it applicable for the wrong committed with the intent to cause injury to the car of Alice. The insurance that would make Bob’s vehicle insured for uninsured motorist coverage not to kick in does not and shall not exist. In’s’ A pays up

Comment: @kisspuska But she does have to prove that and it might not be apparent on the face of what she knows, even if Bob committed an intentional act and cannot himself be an insurance beneficiary.

Comment: She only has to prove intentionality of a motorist to injury her property in that motorists collision with her car for her UIM policy to apply by the operation of law. That’s the bottom line. Of course, anyone can dispute anything they want, but the consequences can be dire for insurance companies. The objective here is not to go to court, but to get insurance to work for what the law designed it. And Alice got a “non-admission-just-business-decision” offer from insurer A to undertake its duties as though it was liable in 1 hour after some of the above cases were laid out, & a single question:

Comment: “Do you agree that it is reasonably clear that if [Bob] acted with intent to cause damage to my property (the vehicle covered under my policy) and with that intent causing the collision, [Bob] is an uninsured motorist or underinsured motorist?” They would have a duty to get to promptly paying per § 790.03(h)(5) and to not conceal if that is the case per paragraph (1) or (2). So insurer A called, and yielded Alice’s claim.

Comment: @kisspuska No she doesn't and that is not the bottom line, because that isn't enough to show a lack of insurance even though it is one important factor. By definition, nobody can be compelled to do anything without going to court. Nobody has to settle out of court. It may be wise to settle but that's all. You seem to see Alice filing suit as some huge imposition, but it is pretty much the norm.

Comment: “Do you agree that it is reasonably clear that if [Bob] acted with intent to cause damage to my property (the vehicle covered under my policy) and with that intent causing the collision, [Bob] is an uninsured motorist or underinsured motorist?” No. It might be a reasonable case to settle for any of the parties involved, but it isn't definitionally true without more facts.

Comment: If an Alice is rammed, the Alice has one burden of proof to meet: Make it reasonably clear to an insurer A that a Bob caused the damage with intent to injure the property, Alice, legally, has no duty to prove that her uninsured policy applies, the insurer A must have reasonable policies in place to handle a claim like this and not allow for its adjusters to misrepresent the law which is a part of the contest as fully as if referenced in the contract. In reality, it might be a less plausible scenario, and the Alice would need to bring this to the attention of the insurer A, but she has no duty.

Comment: "Alice, legally, has no duty to prove that her uninsured policy applies" While the insurer has to act in good faith, she does have to prove that her uninsured policy applies. If all she shows is that she is rammed, she hasn't met that burden. The fact that the drive has no coverage does not automatically imply that it is an uninsured vehicle.

Comment: An Insurer A _does_ have a duty settle: “[It is an] unfair method[] of competition and[/or] deceptive act[] or practice in the business of insurance [to k]nowingly [... m]is representing to claimants pertinent facts or insurance policy provisions relating to any coverages at issue [... or **n]ot attempting in good faith to effectuate prompt, fair and equitable settlements of claims in which liability has become reasonably clear”. An insurer A still _can_ deny coverage while it became reasonably clear that a Bob was malicious, but that doesn’t mean it did not have to settle & can be punished 4.

Comment: @kisspuska It isn't reasonably clear that there is no insurance, only that the driver's conduct was intentional. One does not automatically imply the other, even though it is often the case. There is no misrepresentation by the insurance company involved.

Comment: To this conclusion you also have to read paragraph (3) into the above cites: that provides an insurer A has a duty to adopt and implement reasonable standards for the prompt investigation and processing of claims arising under insurance policies. The law provides they must offer UIM coverage, so it is common enough along with the rising frequency of road rages that they simplify their processes and let the insured know all they have to do is prove malice or intent to cause damage to the property and causing damage to the property as a result.

Comment: @kisspuska Your legal analysis regarding what the insured needs to prove is wrong. There is nothing more to say about it.

Comment: Unfair practice and is illegal: (3) Failing to adopt and implement reasonable standards for the prompt investigation and processing of claims arising under insurance policies.” In what scenario could a Bob’s vehicle not be an uninsured motor vehicle if the Bob maliciously rams an Alice’s? Just give me one example for California.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133730/discussion-between-ohwilleke-and-kisspuska).